# How to avoid indentation on a markerless footnote in plain TeX

Tags: footnotes, plain-tex

I'd like to create a markerless footnote in plain TeX with several lines and no indentation. The closest I've gotten is:

```
\footnote{}{
\kern -2.3em Line 1\hfil\break
\noindent    Line 2\hfil\break
\noindent    Line 3
}
```

since `\noindent` does not work on the first line, but neither `\kern -2.3em` nor `\kern -2.4em` does the job exactly, as the first line is not well aligned with the rest. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The footnote number is placed in a box of width `\parindent`, through `\textindent`.

```
\footnote{}{\kern-\parindent
Line 1\hfil\break
Line 2\hfil\break
Line 3
}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I also realized my example is leaving an unwanted space after the first opening brace.